# Creating list of read details from firestore flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am using firestore to retrieve data

```
List<Data> userSearchItems = [];
...........
 for (var i = 0; i<userDocument['order'].length; i++)...[
        Text(userDocument["order"][i].toString()),
        
        userSearchItems.add(userDocument["order"][i].toString()),//This do not work a read line appears with error  
        
    ],
```

errors seen for *userDocument["order"][i].toString()*

> The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Data'

and a red line also appears at *add*

Using for loop i can get the Text but i want to store it in an array or list (what is most suitable) to be used later to get data from firestore that match a list/array item that has been fetched before

Comment: the `List` type Data, do you have a class for it?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution

You can implement a new method for it

```
var arr=List();
void addList() {
    
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("points").doc('1').get().then((value){
      
      arr.addAll(value['order']);
      
    });

  }
```

and the list can be used in any other function